# How to optimize SQL query which involves GROUP_CONCAT function with ORDER BY

Tags: innodb, optimization, mariadb, group-by, group-concatenation

I wrote the following SQL query to group results and then sort results in each group by date:

```
SELECT 
origin,
provider,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(price
            ORDER BY departure_date
            SEPARATOR ','),
        ',',
        10)
FROM
    `flights`
WHERE
    origin = 'LHR' AND destination IN ('FCO', 'CDG', 'AMS')
        AND cabin_type = 'ECONOMY'
GROUP BY origin , provider;
```

Second query:

```
SELECT 
destination,
provider,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(price
            ORDER BY departure_date
            SEPARATOR ','),
        ',',
        10)
FROM
    `flights`
WHERE
    origin = 'LHR' AND destination IN ('FCO', 'CDG', 'AMS')
        AND cabin_type = 'ECONOMY'
GROUP BY destination, provider;
```

InnoDB table `flights` is quite simple:

```
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+-----------+----------------+
| Field          | Type          | Null | Key | Default   | Extra          |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+-----------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL      | auto_increment |
| origin         | varchar(255)  | NO   | MUL | NULL      |                |
| destination    | varchar(255)  | NO   | MUL | NULL      |                |
| departure_date | date          | NO   | MUL | NULL      |                |
| price          | decimal(14,2) | NO   |     | NULL      |                |
| provider       | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | airnet    |                |
| cabin_type     | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | ECONOMY   |                |
| created_at     | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL      |                |
| updated_at     | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL      |                |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+-----------+----------------+
```

I have indexes on columns: `origin, destination, departure_date`. And approx. 10 million records in the table.

Above-mentioned query takes about 200 to 600 milliseconds. I tried to use profiler and found out that most of the time is spent on `Creating sort index` (approx. 98% of whole query time).

Is there any way to optimize this query. I tried compund index on `origin, provider, departure_date`, but that did not seem to help. Maybe configuration should be tweaked more and if so which configuration variables must be considered?

Machine has 4 GB of RAM, 2 vCPUs and dedicated for DB only (10.3.13-Maria DB).

Comment: Create index lime `flights(origin, destination, cabin_type)` (it seems for this query you can use any possible fields order in this index).

Comment: @Akina Thanks for your help. I added this compound index, unfortunately queries execution time remains approximately  the same.

Comment: What is the result of `SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT origin, provider) FROM flights`. Approximate is enough.

Comment: @Akina The result is: `10633304|9578`.

Answer (score 1):

Test

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT origin,
                     provider,
                     price,
                     departure_date,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY /* origin, */ provider
                                        ORDER BY departure_date) rn 
              FROM flights
              WHERE origin = 'LHR' 
                AND destination IN ('FCO', 'CDG', 'AMS')
                AND cabin_type = 'ECONOMY' )
SELECT origin,
       provider,
       GROUP_CONCAT(price
                    ORDER BY departure_date
                    SEPARATOR ',')
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 10
GROUP BY origin, 
         provider;
```

**UPDATE:** (draft code, see comments)

```
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT origin,
                 provider,
                 price,
                 departure_date,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY provider
                                    ORDER BY departure_date) rn 
          FROM flights
          WHERE origin = 'LHR' 
            AND destination ='FCO'
            AND cabin_type = 'ECONOMY' ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT origin,
                 provider,
                 price,
                 departure_date
          from cte1
          WHERE rn <= 10),
cte3 AS ( SELECT origin,
                 provider,
                 price,
                 departure_date,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY provider
                                    ORDER BY departure_date) rn 
          FROM flights
          WHERE origin = 'LHR' 
            AND destination = 'CDG'
            AND cabin_type = 'ECONOMY' ),
cte4 AS ( SELECT origin,
                 provider,
                 price,
                 departure_date
          from cte3
          WHERE rn <= 10),
cte5 AS ( SELECT origin,
                 provider,
                 price,
                 departure_date,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY provider
                                    ORDER BY departure_date) rn 
          FROM flights
          WHERE origin = 'LHR' 
            AND destination = 'AMS'
            AND cabin_type = 'ECONOMY' ),
cte6 AS ( SELECT origin,
                 provider,
                 price,
                 departure_date
          from cte5
          WHERE rn <= 10),
cte7 AS ( SELECT origin,
                 provider,
                 price,
                 departure_date
          FROM cte2
          UNION ALL
          SELECT origin,
                 provider,
                 price,
                 departure_date
          FROM cte4
          UNION ALL
          SELECT origin,
                 provider,
                 price,
                 departure_date
          FROM cte6 )
cte8 as ( SELECT origin,
                 provider,
                 price,
                 departure_date,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY provider
                                        ORDER BY departure_date) rn 
           FROM cte7)
SELECT origin,
       provider,
       GROUP_CONCAT(price
                    ORDER BY departure_date
                    SEPARATOR ',')
FROM cte8
WHERE rn <= 10
GROUP BY origin, 
         provider;
```

Comment: Yes, this one does execute faster, thanks. There is one more query I want to optimize, quite similar actually, I added it as second query in the description. Number of possible destinations can be more than 3.

Comment: @user882027 Can't you replace `origin` with `destination` yourself?

Comment: Never mind, I try to look for ways to optimize that second query on my own.

Comment: @user882027 Optimizing way is the same - avoid GROUP_CONCAT of all values (which is over 1000) by enumerating and limiting them.

Comment: Yes, I think I understand the technique, however it seems that more destinations I add longer it takes to execute. That is in both original and optimized solutions. I am not sure if smth faster can be achieved in this case anyway. Lots of records must be checked and there is no way around that I am afraid.

Comment: Of course, when algo is the same and the records count increases then the execution time increases too. The only way to increase performance which I can find is to divide the query to 3 separate queries, one `destination` each, select 10 records for each, the union all them and select 10 records again. For such separate query the index by `(origin, destination, cabin_type, origin, provider, departure_date)` will help. Or ever covering index (`price` additionally).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "one `destination` each"? Separate query for each destination (currently defined as cte)?

Comment: @user882027 *Can you explain what you mean by "one destination each"?* One with `destination='FCO'`, another with `destination='CDG'`, ... I'll add draft to the answer.

Comment: @user882027 Draft code added - look. And look for the first code edit (excess partition expression part commented).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91585/discussion-between-user882027-and-akina).

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE
origin = 'LHR' AND destination IN ('FCO', 'CDG', 'AMS')
    AND cabin_type = 'ECONOMY'
```

begs for either of these composite indexes:

```
INDEX(origin, cabin_type, destination)
INDEX(cabin_type, origin, destination)
```

`origin` and `destination` look like they could be `CHAR(3)` instead of `VARCHAR(255)`.

`cabin_type` could probably be an `ENUM`, or at least a shorter `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Actually I added composite origin_destination_provider index and it speed up queries significantly. Thanks for VARCHAR shortening suggestions.